# How does indexOf method on string work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, indexof

I was doing a question on codility and came across [this problem](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/5-prefix_sums/genomic_range_query/) for which I wrote something like this:

```
function impact(s) {
    let imp = 4; // max possible impact
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i] === 'A') return 1;
        else if (s[i] === 'C') imp = Math.min(imp, 2);
        else if (s[i] === 'G') imp = Math.min(imp, 3);
        else if (s[i] === 'T') imp = Math.min(imp, 4);
    }
    return imp;
}

function solution(S, P, Q) {
    const A = new Array(P.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < P.length; i++) {
        const s = S.slice(P[i], Q[i] + 1);
        A[i] = impact(s);
    }
    return A;
}
```

And [it failed all the performance tests](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingRUZCV3-6C5/)

Now I changed it to the following code which I thought would be slower but to my surprise [it scored 100%](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingFD8N6C-75T/):

```
function solution(S, P, Q) {
    let A = []
    for (let i = 0; i < P.length; i++) {
        let s = S.slice(P[i], Q[i] + 1)
        if (s.indexOf('A') > -1) A.push(1)
        else if (s.indexOf('C') > -1) A.push(2)
        else if (s.indexOf('G') > -1) A.push(3)
        else if (s.indexOf('T') > -1) A.push(4)
    }
    return A
}
```

Which to me made no sense, because I was using 4 `indexOf` which should be slower than 1 linear iteration of the same string. But it's not.

So, how does String.`indexOf()` work and why are 4 `.indexOf` so much faster than 1 iteration?

Comment: You may want to look at [this](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.indexof).

Answer (score 1):

In your first solution you have two loops. The second loop is in `impact`. That second loop corresponds roughly to the four `indexOf` you have in the second solution.

One iteration of the second loop will do at most 4 comparisons, and there will be at most *n* iterations. So this makes at most *4n* comparisons. The same can be said of the `indexOf` solution. Each of these four `indexOf` may need to scan the whole array, which represents *n* comparisons. And so that also amounts to a worst case of *4n* comparisons.

The main difference however, is that the scanning that an `indexOf` performs, is not implemented in JavaScript, but in highly efficient pre-compiled code, while the first solution does this scanning with (slower) JavaScript code. As a rule of thumb, it is always more efficient to use native String/Array methods (like there are `indexOf`, `slice`, `includes`,...) than implementing a similar functionality with an explicit `for` loop.

Another thing to consider is that if there is an "A" in the data at position *i*, then the second solution will find it after *i* comparisons (internal to the `indexOf` implementation), while the first solution will find it after *4i* comparisons, because it *also* makes the comparisons for the other three letters during the same iterations in which it looks for an "A". This extra cost decreases for when there is no "A", but a "C" somewhere, ...etc.

Comment: So what you are implying is that even after V8's optimizations, if a string has only `T`s, 3 iterations in native code behind `indexOf` are faster than a single for loop iteration in JavaScript?

Comment: Well, *if* you would have four separate loops that completely mimic the `indexOf` operations, I guess it *could* be optimised a lot, but your first solution criss-crosses between four targets of the search, so it is not quite the same sequence of processing.